# How to design such a layout? Should I use a recyclerview, a viewpager or something else?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

[image: First page user can swipe in red area to change pages or select any drink to choose sauces from image 3]

[image: user swiped or selected page 2]

[image: when user selects from image 1 or 2 this page (sauces step) is opened]

I want to design a layout similar to the images where user selects one item in each step (drink,sauce...) user advances next step (and its displayed in stepper). user can also swipe(in red area) or click one of "1,2,3,4,5" pages to change page.

I searched how to do it with recyclerview but couldn't find a solution. What layout do i need to use for such case. just need to know how to achieve similar designs. I don't need code or xml for solution just an explanation will be enough.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. You have to add `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. Than, your `TabLayout` should have different `TabLayout` inside of that `ViewPager`.
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for answering what do i use for the content inside red area

Comment: The `viewPager` will handle swiping between fragments for you